# Modify picture colour of button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, shader

In a WPF application, i insert a button with a simple picture on background :

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20">
    <Button.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="Divalto_Rechercher_25px.png" Stretch="Uniform"></ImageBrush>
    </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

I would like to, on Mouse Over, transforme the picture colour of the picture.

Here is the picture when mouse is out :

[image]

And when mouse is over, i would like a thing like this :

[image]

I would like to do this dynamically (transforming the picture colour dynamicaly).

Here is a try, but not complete :

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Margin="15,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20">
  <Button.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="appbar.feature.search.rest.png" Stretch="Uniform"></ImageBrush>
  </Button.Background> 
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseEnter">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="AnimBrush" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:5" 
                    AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</Button>
```

Anyone could help me please ?

Thanks a lot,

Best regards,

Answer (score 2):

You could just create the `Content` as a `Border` with an `Image` inside and change the `Border` `Background` using a `Trigger` or `Animation`. It may also be a good idea to override the `Button` template if you just want to show the image style otherwise you will get the Buuttons focus style when the mouse is over.

Example:

```
 <Button BorderBrush="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="12,24,0,238" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="51">
        <Button.Content>
            <Border CornerRadius="5">
                <Image Margin="3" Source="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/custom-icon-design/mini/32/Search-icon.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
                <Border.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LimeGreen" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Border.Style>
            </Border>
        </Button.Content>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" >
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Result:

Normal [image] MouseOver [image]

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the button content to be the image that you want? That is probably the easiest way. Then, you can just change on mouse events. [See this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2783619/how-do-i-animate-image-content-in-wpf)

If you have an image that is the white magnifying glass only, with the rest of the image transparent then you should set the button content to be the image and set the background to be the color that you want (orange or black)

Comment: because i could change programmatically the coulor ! Thats why i would like to transform my picture :)

Comment: If you are looking to change the color only, then you are going to have to build the image via WPF drawing AFAIK...unless the image is only the magnifying glass with the rest transparent?

Comment: Interressant ! Supposing i have the magnifying glass with the rest transparent, how could i add dynamically the black coluor, and the orange colour ?

Comment: I just updated my answer to reflect what you would need to do

Comment: Yes, but how can i change de colour please on my transparent picture please :) ?

Comment: You wont be changing the picture, you will be changing the background of the button, which should show through the transparency of the image. Otherwise, you will need to go with my first suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to add a StoryBoard to your XAML.  If you have a transparent image, why not simply change the fill color of the button?

I haven't tested the below code, but it is something you can use as a springboard.

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseOver">
      <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard>
          <ColorAnimation
            Storyboard.TargetName="AnimBrush" 
            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
            From="Red" To="Green" Duration="0:0:5" 
            AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
        </Storyboard>
      </BeginStoryboard>
 </EventTrigger>
```

Comment: thanks :) i tried to use this code, but the colou don't change. I edit the first post with my code, could you take a look please ? thanks :)